# Youtube design change for iframe videos - full srceen button vanished

Tags: youtube-api

my colleauge and I created a website for a customer last month with several Youtube videos.
http://www.doepfner.de/filme.html

It worked very well and the customer was happy. Then I was 2 weeks on vacation. Now the design of the player has changed slightly. Biggest problem: the full screen button vanished. I tried to use the fs parameter to force it but nothing happend.

Can somebody tell me if it is possible to get the full screen button back or the other design?

Comment: I was going to recommend the [allowfullscreen attribute](https://wiki.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Gecko:FullScreenAPI#iframe_allowfullscreen_attribute) but it looks like that may already be present in your iframe tag...

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by you getting the HTML5 video player over Flash.  This could have happened a couple ways.  The most likely is you don't have Flash installed(or didn't at one point) and were opted into an experiment.  You can opt out of the HTML5 experiment by going to http://www.youtube.com/html5.  This will only effect your browser and not your users, but my guess is they're not having the same issues(assuming they have flash installed).

The other option is a bit of a hack(sort of).  If you add webkitallowfullscreen and mozallowfullscreen as attributes to the iframe.  This will allow the js fullscreen api to work in Firefox and Chrome.  This api is not yet a finalized standard but should be soon.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. I have flash installed and also use html5 on Youtube.